# How to implement mozilla web push notifications in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, push-notification, web-push

I'd like to implement Mozilla web-push notifications in website.

Would someone give me an example of code on how to implement web-push notifications in Rails4 ?

have been struggling since a week none of my tries have been successful.

Comment: If you don't mind using a service check out this gem: https://github.com/pushpad/pushpad-ruby

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. It's looking something as i wanted.

Comment: is it possible to add a sender without GCM API key, APN because i only want notifications on mozilla @collimarco ?

Comment: APNs certs are optional, you can leave them blank. GCM is required but you can get a **totally free** API key with a few steps: https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_requirements

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help. i will use the same.